# Unity standalone app with sqlite functionality cannot read the database

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I created a simple unity 2021.3.13 app with sqlite functionality. The app is supposed to read the database (created with DB Browser for SQLite) and print out on unity canvas the number of entries. The app runs on unity editor, runs when installed as standalone in the PC where it was developed, but when installed on any other pc it prints out null.
The same app when build for android it runs as apk but when build for windows it does not.

I opened the app's folder and i checked if the database exists and it does. The user has permission to read and write the database.
I added the following plugins I18N.CJK.dll, I18N.dll, I18N.MidEast.dll, I18N.Rare.dll, I18N.West.dll
and System.Data.dll but again runs in the pc where it was developed but at no other machine.

Comment: Is the connection string to the database designed in such a way that it hits the local database instead of the one found on your PC?  Maybe it works on your PC because it is routed to hit your PC, but when its on another PC it can't reach your PC over the network.  This could explain why it only works on your PC.

Comment: There are far too many things that could be wrong. Please provide steps to recreate

Comment: Trying to figure out what the problem is, I added two Unity UI txet objects on canvas and set the first one to printout the path to database and the second one to print out the number of elements found.   public static string dbPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "mydatabase.db");
public static string connectionString = "Data Source=" + dbPath;            dbPathText.text = ReadDatabase.connectionString; Again in my PC it shows the path and the number of elements found but on another machine it prints the path to the local folder but for elements found it prints 0.